# S3PersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter produces messages for the existing/synchronized files on application restart

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

has anyone come across that? basically I aim to process the file once even if the application is bounced

```
@Bean
public S3InboundFileSynchronizer s3InboundFileSynchronizer() throws Exception {
    S3InboundFileSynchronizer synchronizer = new S3InboundFileSynchronizer(amazonS3());
    synchronizer.setDeleteRemoteFiles(false);
    synchronizer.setPreserveTimestamp(true);
    synchronizer.setRemoteDirectory(sourceBucket + "/dir/");
    synchronizer.setFilter(new S3PersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(new SimpleMetadataStore(), "simpleMetadataStore"));
    return synchronizer;
}

private AmazonS3 amazonS3() throws Exception {      
    return clientFactory.getClient(AmazonS3.class);
}

@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(value = "s3FilesChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "5000"))
public S3InboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource s3InboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource() throws Exception {
    S3InboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource messageSource =
            new S3InboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(s3InboundFileSynchronizer());
    messageSource.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
    messageSource.setLocalDirectory(new File("c:/temp/"));
    messageSource.setLocalFilter(new FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(new SimpleMetadataStore(), "fsSimpleMetadataStore"));             
    return messageSource;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem that you use an in-memory `SimpleMetadataStore`, so after application restart you lose all the information stored there.

Consider to use some persistent store implementation instead, e.g. for AWS we have a `DynamoDbMetadataStore`: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-aws#metadata-store-for-amazon-dynamodb

Comment: is there any SimpleMetadataStore using FileSystem for persistance?

Comment: Yes, `PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.8.RELEASE/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html#metadata-store

Comment: still doesn't work with PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore, it produces a message on launch for a file it downloaded already and it also detects that logs "has not been transferred to the existing local file 'c:\temp\a\b\file.xml'. Consider removing the local file"

Comment: Your need to clean up that local directory

Comment: Before running your tests

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand how this works:

For an entry already downloaded, I expect not to produce any message
So the log makes sense, but why it produces a message I don’t get


If I go and clean up the local directory, I expect it to download the file again and produce a message for the successive channel (which is what it does)

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: If file is there in local dir, then downloaded entry is ignored, but message is still produced for this entry. To avoid that you need to have a file list filter mention above.